# laravel passing multiple variables from different queries to a view

Tags: laravel, foreach, controller, eloquent

I have different queries that are to be selected under different time periods.
I want to pass them to a view

```
$sales = DB::table('sales')
        ->join('drugs', 'drugs.id', '=', 'sales.drug_id')
        ->select('sales.*','drugs.name', DB::raw('sum(sales.quantity_sold) as total_sales'))
        ->whereYear('date_sold','>','2014')
        ->whereYear('date_sold','<','2017')            
        ->get()->groupBy('sales.drug_id');

$stocks = DB::table('sales')
         ->join('drugs', 'drugs.id', '=', 'sales.drug_id')
         ->select('sales.*','drugs.name', DB::raw ('AVG(sales.quantity_sold) as average_sales'))
         ->whereMonth('date_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)             
         ->get()->groupBy('sales.drug_id');

$data = $sales->merge($stocks);
```

In my view I want to have a table whereby I will have the drug,total sales and average sales in a row.

```
 @foreach($data as $key => $item)
    <tr id="item{{$item->id}}">                                                                             <td>{{$item->name}}</td>    
                 <td>{{$item->total_sales}}</td>    
                 <td>{{number_format($item->average_stocks,0)}}</td>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `return view('viewname', ['sales' => $sales, 'stocks' => $stocks])` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, group both the collection objects by the common field (drug_id) like so:

```
$sales = DB::table('sales')
        ->join('drugs', 'drugs.id', '=', 'sales.drug_id')
        ->select('sales.*','drugs.name', DB::raw('sum(sales.quantity_sold) as total_sales'))
        ->whereYear('date_sold','>','2014')
        ->whereYear('date_sold','<','2017')
        ->groupBy('sales.drug_id')
        ->get()->groupBy('drug_id');

$stocks = DB::table('stocks')
         ->join('drugs', 'drugs.id', '=', 'stocks.drug_id')
         ->select('stocks.*','drugs.name', DB::raw ('AVG(stocks.quantity_sold) as average_stocks'))
         ->whereMonth('date_sold','=', Carbon::today()->month)
         ->groupBy('stocks.drug_id')
         ->get()->groupBy('drug_id');
```

Then, merge both the collections like so:

```
$data = $sales->merge($stocks);
```

Finally, inject the data in the view from your controller like so:

```
return view('viewname', compact('data'));
```

Comment: i get an error, Call to a member function merge() on a non-object

Comment: Can you dd($sales) to check what $sales looks like?

Comment: For the sales::  array:3 [▼
  0 => {#323 ▼
    +"name": "Isoniazid,300mg"
    +"total_sales": "409"
  }
  1 => {#324 ▼
    +"name": "Dapsone,100mgs"
    +"total_sales": "256"
  }
  2 => {#325 ▼
    +"name": "Nevirapine,200mgs"
    +"total_sales": "384"
  }
]    and for the stock:  array:3 [▼
  0 => {#326 ▼
    +"name": "Isoniazid,300mg"
    +"average_sales": "37.5000"
  }
  1 => {#327 ▼
    +"name": "Dapsone,100mgs"
    +"average_sales": "20.8462"
  }
  2 => {#328 ▼
    +"name": "Nevirapine,200mgs"
    +"average_sales": "32.0000"
  }
]

Comment: did you add the groupBy at the end of both $sales and $stock? If you did, please post the complete error stack

Comment: When i put groupBy(sales.drug_id) after get(), the error is call to a member function groupBy on a non-object

Comment: It needs to be after get() because get() fires the query and returns an Eloquent collection object and groupBy on a collection object returns another collection. Finally we call merge on this collection. Can you post the updated code?

Comment: check the question, it has the updated code.Did as you suggested,  the error is call to a member function groupBy on a non-object

Comment: Try the code that I have posted exactly in my answer earlier. There are 2 groupBy function calls

Comment: tried that too.. same error. It seems the query doesn't return an object no idea why

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, doesn't look like I'll be able to debug this